# Append values from a data frame to a list created in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, pdf, pdftools

*Edit: Thanks to Martin and a little bit of time and attention, I was able to get the code where I needed it to be. Is it ugly? Yes, but it works in way that's useful to me now. Any tips on how to clean this up and make it more efficient would be super helpful.

Using the data frame `trace_list`, I'm trying to append the values from `Title` and `Year` to the output of each list in the for loop. The following code opens each state's PDF link on page 10, pulls the city data (which ranges from 1-12 cities). Clean/tidies the data, and stores it in a list to be bound after data from each PDF is collected. <strike>Right now it only pulls the city name and a numerical value.</strike>

```
data.frame(Link = c('https://www.atf.gov/file/146951/download','https://www.atf.gov/file/146966/download','https://www.atf.gov/file/146976/download','https://www.atf.gov/file/137041/download','https://www.atf.gov/file/137231/download','https://www.atf.gov/file/137301/download','https://www.atf.gov/docs/undefined/flwebsite17183911pdf/download','https://www.atf.gov/docs/undefined/kywebsite17183876pdf/download','https://www.atf.gov/docs/undefined/prwebsite17183917pdf/download'), Title = c('Alabama','California','District of Columbia','Alaska','Pennsylvania','Wyoming','Florida','Kentucky','Puerto Rico'), Year = c('2019','2019','2019','2018','2018','2018','2017','2017','2017'))
library(pdftools)
library(dplyr)
library(tabulizer)
library(english)
library(gsubfn)
library(rebus)
library(htmlwidgets)

citytrace <- list()
trace_list <- as.data.frame(trace_list)
for (i in seq_len(nrow(trace_list[c(1:159),]))) {
  pdf_link <- trace_list[i, 1]
  pdf_link <- paste0('',pdf_link,'')
  
  gpi_table <- tabulizer::extract_tables(pdf_link,output = "data.frame",pages = c(10, 10), area = list(c(230,0,280,717), c(275,0,321,725)),guess = F)
  
  city <- list(gpi_table)[[1]][[1]]
  #city <- city[!Reduce(`|`, lapply(city[1], grepl, pattern = '^[0-9]+$""')),]
  city[city==""] <- NA
  city <- setNames(rbind(names(city), city), names(city))
  colnames(city) <- paste("V",seq(1,length(city),1),sep="")
  #city <- ifelse(city[1,]=='city',city[-1,],city)
  city <- if(length(city)>4){
    a <- data.frame(t(city))
    colnames(a) <- paste("X",seq(1,length(a),1),sep="")
    a[,1] <- factor(paste(a$X1,a$X2,a$X3,a$X4, sep = " "))
    a[,1] <- trimws(gsub("X|X\\.[[:digit:]]|\\.[[:digit:]]","",a$X1))
    a <- a[,-c(2:4)]
  } else {
    city %>%
      unite(city, 1:length(city), sep = " ", remove = FALSE) %>%
      mutate_all(na_if,"") %>%
      drop_na() %>%
      mutate(city = trimws(city), city = str_replace(city,"  "," ")) %>%
      select(city)
  }
  city <- ifelse(grepl(c("X|[[:digit:]]"),city),sapply(city, function(x) gsub(c('"*"|[[:digit:]]+|X|,|\\.|^c\\(|\\)$|'),"",x)),sapply(city, function(x) gsub("\\."," ",x)))
  city <- unique(data.frame(matrix(unlist(city), nrow=length(city), byrow=TRUE)))
  city[which(city=="" | city=="NA"),] <- NA
  city <- city[complete.cases(city), , drop=FALSE]
  colnames(city) <- "city"
  
  count <- list(gpi_table)[[1]][[2]]
  count <- setNames(rbind(names(count), count), names(count))
  colnames(count) <- paste("V",seq(1,length(count),1),sep="")
  count <- ifelse(grepl("^X[[:digit:]]+$|^X[[:digit:]]+\\.[[:digit:]]+$",count),sapply(count,function(x) gsub("X|\\.[[:digit:]]$","",x)),count)
  count <- cbind(city,count)
  
  library(english)
  library(gsubfn)
  result <- pdf_text(pdf_link)[10]  %>%
    str_split("\n") %>%
    first() %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    mutate_all(list(~na_if(.,""))) %>%
    filter(grepl("NOTE:|determined",value))
  x3 <- ifelse(is.na(result[2,]),paste(result[1,], result[2,], sep=". "),paste(result[1,], result[2,], sep=" "))
  x3 <- dplyr::tibble(line = 1, text = x3)
  sv <- strsplit(x3$text, split = "\\. ")
  x3 <- data.frame(V1 = rep(x3$line, sapply(sv, length)), V2 = unlist(sv))
  x3[1,2] <- gsubfn("\\w+", setNames(as.list(1:10), as.english(1:10)), x3[1,2])
  x3[2,2] <- gsubfn("\\w+", setNames(as.list(1:10), as.english(1:10)), x3[2,2])
  x3$V2 <- gsub(",","",x3$V2)
  x3$V2 <- gsub("NA",0,x3$V2)
  x3$city <- ifelse(grepl("additional",x3$V2),"Other","None")
  
  library(rebus)
  library(htmlwidgets)
  trcount <- DGT %R% optional(DGT) %R% optional(DGT) %R% optional(DGT) %R% optional(DGT)
  str_view_all(x3$V2, 
               pattern = trcount)
  a0 <- str_match_all(x3$V2, pattern = trcount)
  a0[[1]] <- a0[[1]][-1,1]
  x3$count <- unlist(a0)
  x4 <- as.data.frame(x3[,-c(1:2)])
  x5 <- rbind(count,x4)
  
  x5 <- x5 %>% 
    mutate(state = trace_list[i, 2],
           year  = trace_list[i, 3]) 
  citytrace[[i]] <- x5
}
citytrace <- do.call(rbind,citytrace)
citytrace$city <- gsub(c(' NA|  '), '', citytrace$city)
citytrace$count <- gsub(c('\\.'), '', citytrace$count)
print(citytrace)
```

What I'm having trouble with is assigning the values in 'Title' and 'Year' from 'trace_list' to the looped output. Expected results below:

| city | count | state | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Birmingham | 100 | Alabama | 2019 |
| Fairbanks | 10 | Alaska | 2018 |

<strike>I'm not exactly sure how to start doing that and was looking for help with that.</strike> Any advice *on how to clean up the code* is greatly appreciated.

Comment: (1) That's a lot of code here. Is this really a _minimal_ reproducible example? (2) You should put the `library(...)` statements on top of your code. Inside a `for`-loop they are hard to spot and you don't (want to) load them several times.

Comment: Fixed 2. What do you need for a reproducible example? 10?

Comment: I can't run your code, but I think your problem doesn't need all the code shown. If I understand it right, you have an output in some form and just want to add the state and year information. So basically you have to show the output, the source for state/year (trace_list) and your desired output.

Comment: That's precisely it.

Comment: How does `x5` at the end of the `for`-loop look like?

Comment: It's a data frame object that lists the cities (column 1) and count (column 2) for the last state in the loop.

Comment: This is definitely not a MINIMAL reprex

Comment: @GuedesBF so, there isn't some guideline that tells me what qualifies as a minimal reprex based on the number of elements in a code. I understand what the guidelines currently are, but I assumed what I offered produced *the* minimal amount required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I can't run your code here a small suggestion for your code

```r
library(dplyr)

for (i in seq_len(nrow(trace_list))) {
  pdf_link <- trace_list[i, 1]
  # Do stuff with the URL
  # probably you don't need the inner for-loop
  # create the data.frame x5
  
  x5 %>% 
    mutate(state = trace_list[i, 2],
           year  = trace_list[i, 3]) 
}
```

Some remarks:

- I don't understand the definition of your `for`-loop: iterating over `list(trace_list[c(1:2),])` doesn't make any sense for me.
- Extracting and storing the `url` in `pdf_link` is better done by `pdf_link <- trace_list[i, 1]`.
- Iterating over `unlist(pdf_link)` also doesn't make sense to me. I think you can use `trace_list[i, 1]`, `trace_list[i, 2]` or `trace_list[i, 3]` instead.

Comment: For your first point: I was only selecting the first two rows to test the data. I fixed it now but that was my mistake for including it in there. 
So when I ran tabulizer::extract_tables, I was receiving an error. Basically it was only selecting the first link to run the function. I looked online, and I gathered that the column for the URLs needed to be a vector. I don't know how to explain it beyond it that the function works now.